# How to return .find() as a response using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I'm learning Flask and I would like to append documents that I got from pymongo into ret and return 20 of those as a response.
I've found many solutions online but I couldn't found any.
Thanks for your time.

This is the printed result:
{'_id': ObjectId('5f6d8b87c8dcc2089446a153'), 'id': '5959764021', 'quiz1': 8, 'quiz2': 3, 'quiz3': 6, 'quiz4': 2, 'quiz5': 2, 'sum': 21}

TypeError: Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable

```
@app.route('/get')
def findScore():
  id_param= str(request.args.get('id'))
  ret = dict()
  cursor = db.scores.find({"id": { "$gt": id_param }}).sort("id",1).limit(20) #ascending
  for document in cursor:
    print(document)
    ret = document
    
  #print(str(ret))
  return jsonify(ret)

app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `type()` of `objectid` which is an instance.

You can use [json_utils](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html) to handle the BSON type before returning the value.

```
@app.route('/get')
def findScore():
  id_param= str(request.args.get('id'))
  ret = dict()
  cursor = db.scores.find({"id": { "$gt": id_param }}).sort("id",1).limit(20) #ascending
  for document in cursor:
    print(document)
    ret = document
  return jsonify(json_utils.dumps(ret))

app.run()
```